How to use ComfyUI for running stable diffusion models?
I wan to know if there is a way in which without much GPU utilization, one can use ComfyUI for garment imposition on another image.
I have until now watched few YT videos but most of them are prominently have GPU utilization.

Sharing Stack Overflow posting etiquette link to know how ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I don't know about garments in particular, but running ComfyUI without GPU is possible. I run ComfyUI using python3 main.py --cpu and can use many popular image generation models this way. Of course it's dog slow. And you may also run out of RAM if you use one of the larger models. Stable Diffusion 1.5 should be fine though, it uses only a GB of RAM.
